# Erro de conversão do valor varchar para inteiro

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-core

Ao realizar o seguinte `UPDATE` através da minha API (.NET Core):

```
UPDATE Aula
SET WHATEVER = WHATEVER
WHERE ID_AULA = @examID
```

Código:

```
string query = builder
    .AppendLine("UPDATE Aula")
    .AppendLine("SET WHATEVER = WHATEVER")
    .AppendLine("WHERE ID_AULA = @examID").ToString();

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection);

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@examID", item.ExamID);

sqlConnection.Open();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Recebo o seguinte erro: `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '22234390|22234391' to data type int.`

Sendo que meu campo `ID_AULA` é um campo `varchar` e o parâmetro `@examID` vem de uma propriedade `string`.

Se faço a mesma operação pelo banco dessa forma, funciona:

```
UPDATE Aula
SET WHATEVER = WHATEVER
WHERE ID_AULA = '22245089|22245090'
```

Porque ocorre isso e como corrigir?

Comment: Coloque um trecho maior do código por favor

Comment: @RovannLinhalis feito

Comment: você fala do campo ID_AULA, mas no seu código vc usa o campo ID_AULA_DETRAN, tem certeza que é o mesmo campo?

Comment: @JúlioNeto foi erro meu na hora de omitir o nome dos campos haha, mas sim, estou usando o campo certo.

Comment: como está a declaração de `item.ExamID` ?

Comment: @RovannLinhalis uma propriedade string normal public string ExamID {get;set;}

Comment: tentou declarar o tipo no SqlParameter? 
`command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@examID", DbType = DbType.String, Value = item.ExamID });`

Comment: Acho que pode ser o que Leandro Angelo falou. Relacionado: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/configuring-parameters-and-parameter-data-types

Comment: @LeandroAngelo muito obrigado!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ao não especificar o DbType do parâmetro, o `SqlCommand` está interpretando-o como inteiro, e sendo assim o caractere `|` no `SQLServer` é um operador `OR bitwise`.

Se você executar o seguinte comando:

```
select 22245089|22245090;
```

O retorno é:

> **22245091** (inteiro)  (ver no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/17086))

**Porque:** (Comparação OU bit a bit)

```
0001010100110110111011100001 = 22245089
0001010100110110111011100010 = 22245090
=======================================
0001010100110110111011100011 = 22245091
```

Então para a query:

```
UPDATE Aula SET WHATEVER = WHATEVER WHERE ID_AULA = @examID
```

A query resultante seria:

```
UPDATE Aula SET WHATEVER = WHATEVER WHERE ID_AULA = 22245089|22245090
```

que processada o operador, ficaria assim:

```
UPDATE Aula SET WHATEVER = WHATEVER WHERE ID_AULA = 22245091
```

por isso a falha.

Faça como Leandro falou, e especifique o formato do parâmetro:

```
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@examID", DbType = DbType.String, Value = item.ExamID });
```

A query resultante deve ser:

```
UPDATE Aula SET WHATEVER = WHATEVER WHERE ID_AULA = '22245089|22245090'
```

**Sobre o SqlParameter:**

De acordo com a [documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0881fz2y.aspx), o construtor espera um `Object`, e quando o tipo do parâmetro não é especificado, ele será inferido pelo tipo do `Object` informado.

Opinião minha: Se o valor do objeto só contém números e um operador, ele pode estar entendendo isso como inteiro, você poderia tentar algo como:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@examID","'"+ item.ExamID + "'");
```

Comment: Utilizei o que o Leandro informou e deu certo! Creio que ele estava entendo como um inteiro mesmo, por isso gerou o erro. Muito obrigado pela ajuda e também muito obrigado ao Leandro!